# How can I display multiple lines in the same compiler error when using :cn?

Tags: vimscript, quickfix

I am using Vim for Rust development.  I have a custom error format that works very well, except that newline characters in error messages are suppressed when scrolling through errors with `:cn`.  This is a problem because `rustc`'s error messages are usually multiple lines.

Is it possible to get Vim to display all of the lines in the error messages, on multiple lines, as they would be displayed on a terminal?

Edit:  My error format is

```
CompilerSet errorformat=
     \%+E%f:%l:%c:\ %*\\d:%*\\d\ error:\ %m,
     \%+W%f:%l:%c:\ %*\\d:%*\\d\ warning:\ %m,
     \%+A%f:%l:%c:\ %*\\d:%*\\d\ note:\ %m,
     \%+C%f:%l:%c:\ error:\ %m,
     \%+C%f:%l:%c:\ warning:\ %m,
     \%+C%f:%l:%c:\ note:\ %m,
     \%+C%f:%l\ %s,
     \%+C\ %m,
     \%+C\(%m,
     \%+G%*[\ ]^,
     \%+G%*[\ ]^%*[~],
     \%+G%*[\ ]...
```

where `:CompilerSet` is defined as:

```
   command -nargs=* CompilerSet setlocal <args>
```

The error message is

```
read.rs:439:26: 439:74 error: mismatched types [E0308]
read.rs:439                     *x = State::DottedList { isSquare: a, depth: length }
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
read.rs:439:26: 439:74 help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
read.rs:439:26: 439:74 note: expected type `&read::read::State` 
read.rs:439:26: 439:74 note:    found type `read::read::State` 
read.rs:439:26: 439:74 note: expected &-ptr, found enum `read::read::State` 
read.rs:439                     *x = State::DottedList { isSquare: a, depth: length }
                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You should show us your `efm` and a sample error.